# Trying to save a list as json file and load it in C#(unity)

Tags: c#, json, list, unity-game-engine

```
public class Mycustom_gameobject_list
{
    public WayspotAnchorPayload game_object_coordinates;
    public GameObject storing_gameobject;
   
}
[Serializable]
public class Gameobject_lsit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> Store_gameobjects_list = new List<Mycustom_gameobject_list>();
}
```

I create a list with a custom class and store some data inside then try to pass the list to the method that is created

```
 public static void SaveLocalPayloads(List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> gamelist)
        {
            List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> gameobjdata = new List<Mycustom_gameobject_list>();
            foreach (var Gamelist in gamelist)
            {
               gameobjdata.Add(Gamelist);
             
            }
         
            var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(gameobjdata);
           PlayerPrefs.SetString(GameobjData, json);
           
            //Debug.Log("Data Center length "+ gameobjdata.Count);
            Debug.Log("what's inside the file "+json);
            //var wayspotAnchorsData = new WayspotAnchorsData();
            //Debug.Log("DataCenter game obj" + gameobj.Length);
            //wayspotAnchorsData.Payloads = wayspotAnchorPayloads.Select(a => a.Serialize()).ToArray();
            //wayspotAnchorsData.gameobj = gameobj.ToArray();
            //Debug.Log("DataCenter Pay load length " + wayspotAnchorsData.Payloads.Length);
            //Debug.Log("DataCenter gameobj length " + wayspotAnchorsData.gameobj.Length);

            //string wayspotAnchorsJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(wayspotAnchorsData);
            //string obj = JsonUtility.ToJson(gameobj);
            //PlayerPrefs.SetString(DataKey, wayspotAnchorsJson);
            //PlayerPrefs.SetString(gamobj, obj);

        }
```

Then I debug the length of the list making sure the data is loading inside, and then I save it as json.

```
public static List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> LoadLocalPayloads()
        {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(GameobjData))
        {
            var json = PlayerPrefs.GetString(GameobjData);
            List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> gameobjectlist = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Mycustom_gameobject_list>>(json);
            Debug.Log("Loading Data " + gameobjectlist);
            Debug.Log("The length of the loading data "+ gameobjectlist.Count);
            //var payloads = new List<WayspotAnchorPayload>();
            //var json = PlayerPrefs.GetString(DataKey);
            //var wayspotAnchorsData = JsonUtility.FromJson<WayspotAnchorsData>(json);
            //foreach (var wayspotAnchorPayload in wayspotAnchorsData.Payloads)
            //{
            //var payload = WayspotAnchorPayload.Deserialize(wayspotAnchorPayload);
            //payloads.Add(payload);
            //}
           // List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> load_gameobject_list = new List<Mycustom_gameobject_list>();
           
            /*foreach (var gameobject in gameobjectlist)
            {
                load_gameobject_list.Add(gameobject);
            }*/
            // var gameobjdata = JsonUtility.FromJson<Mycustom_gameobject_list>(json);
            //foreach (var gameobjects in gameobjdata.)
            
            

                return gameobjectlist;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
       However, when I debug the length of the data that is about to be loaded, it returns 0.
```

Not sure what is the issue and do I have to create a custom class in the script that stores the data?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correctly, you mean deserialize an C# object to json and serialized to JSON to C# object? In this case, I'd use [Newtonsoft.Json](http://json.net/) .

Here is a generic list populated with 20 `FooClass` objects:

```cs
var barList = new List<FooClass>();
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    barList.Add(new FooClass { Index = i, Name = $"Name{i}" });
}

class FooClass
{
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To serialize the list (make it to JSON string):

```
var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(barList);
```

You can write the value of `jsonStr` to a file, or wherever you can fetch it again to get the exact same value as `jsonStr`.

And you can just deserialize the JSON string to object (make string to object)

```
var jsonStrRead = File.ReadAllText("/foobar.json");
var deserializedBarList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FooClass>>(jsonStrRead);
```

`jsonStrRead` is the content of saved file, `deserializedBarList`  is the product of the deserialization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I will test it tomorrow. One more question currently I didn’t serialize the object. I just use Tojson, is it the reason why when I write data to the json file in and can see the list count is two but when it loaded out it’s 0?  And I know the playerPref file save location is different on different platform. But if I’m developing in android platform but currently still testing it on Pc where the file will actually store? Thanks

Comment: Wherever you store the file, it's ok if you can read it correctly. And to be honest I don't really know how do you implement `JsonUtility.ToJson`, I can't predict how's it works, maybe you should show it

Comment: public static void SaveLocalPayloads(List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> gamelist)
        {
            List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> gameobjdata = new List<Mycustom_gameobject_list>();
            foreach (var Gamelist in gamelist)
            {
               gameobjdata.Add(Gamelist);
             
            }
         
            var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(gameobjdata);
           PlayerPrefs.SetString(GameobjData, json);

Comment: I think the problem for me right now is the function not working properly, but more importantly, I cant see the JSON file because I have no idea where it saves. I think right now it's in playerPrefs, and the file storage location is different. When I develop the platform in android but I'm debugging on pc. I can't locate the JSON file location